# how do you resize a CALayer after it's been added as a sublayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a CALayer (CAGradientLayer) added as a subview of a UIImageView. I have successfully added it as a sublayer of the UIImageView, however on orientation I'd like to adjust the layer's width. How can I do so? I tried the following code without any success:

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.imageOverlay setFrame:self.backgroundImageView_.bounds];
    [self.gradientOverlay setFrame:self.view.bounds];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you supporting < iOS 5?  You can override the viewWillLayoutSubviews method on your view controller and try setting the frame there.  Otherwise, create a view subclass to use as the container of the gradient layer and resize the layer in layoutSubviews.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my response... since you don't need to support iOS 4,3, etc... you can manually resizes the layer in viewWillLayoutSubviews